# Making time series prediction and actual plot lines overlap in R?

Tags: r, time-series, data-visualization

I have been working with several time series objects and extracted a HoltWinters() prediction for them, plotting the actual lines against the predictions given by the model. However, in one case I am unable to make the 'actual' line, which I add on top with the lines() function, overlap with the prediction, which I add first. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Here's the issue and the code I used along with it.

```
plot(obs_ets_forecast, plot.conf=FALSE, main="ETS model forecast")

lines(obs, col="black")

legend("bottom", lty=1,bty = "n",col=c("black","blue"),c("Observations","Prediction"))
```

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm having trouble understand what you mean by "actual" lines. At first glance, it would seem that you are asking why predicted and observed values don't perfectly overlap; I'm assuming this is not what you are asking. It would help if you could provide a reproducible example. Could you please provide the output of `dput(obs_ets_forecast)` and `dput(obs)`, or provide other R code to that would generate these objects?

Comment: Hi, I have a time series where the two last weeks of data are my test set. I run my ets model to predict these two last weeks with a training set that corresponds to the whole time series without these 14 days. Then I try to overlap the prediction with the actual time series that contains all observations.. does it make more sense? :)

Comment: A reproducible example (see previous comment; I suggest making use of `dput()`) would help me understand.